# How to install Drivers in Linux

Tags: serial-port

I had fixed a new serial port to my workstation and following the instructions to install the driver for that card, the instructions says:
<1>-copy pci60806a.o to /usr/sbin
<2>-Add /usr/sbin/pci60806a at the end of the /etc/rc.d/rc.local.
<3>-reboot

I had copied the file to /usr/sbin directory but I don't understand step 2
please can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of that?
I opened rc.local file, should I add /usr/sbin/pci60806a to the script? if yes what should be the file name because it gives me save as only

Answer (score 0):

> I opened rc.local file, should I add /usr/sbin/pci60806a to the script? if yes what should be the file name because it gives me save as only

You need sudo permissions to save the file.

Try `sudo nano /etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to go to end of the file and then type the text the instructions tell you to put at the end of that file.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and it will say "file name to write: rc.local". Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will save the rc.local file with your added text. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.